# not able to auto import react components from node modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, material-ui

I have recently started working with vs code. I am using material ui with react and type script. But I am not able to import the components of material ui using alt(option) + enter shortcut. I am using mac and the typescript version that I am using is 3.0.3. However, the react components that I am creating explicitly, those I am able to import using the above mentioned shortcut. Following is the package.json that I am using:

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "ahujru",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "3.0.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "3.0.1",
    "@types/material-ui": "0.21.5",
    "@types/react": "16.4.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.0.7",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "5.2.1",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "4.9.3",
    "react": "16.5.1",
    "react-dom": "16.5.1",
    "sass": "1.13.4",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
    "source-map-loader": "0.2.4",
    "style-loader": "0.23.0",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.54",
    "typescript": "3.0.3",
    "webpack": "4.19.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.8"
  }
}
```

and tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "watch": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "target",
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I have already installed plugins like npm intellisense, intellij keybindings and auto import but still nothings seems to happen. Could someone please tell me what am I missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I can reproduce the problem you are seeing.  Based on my testing, the auto-import functionality built into VS Code only works for symbols defined in files that are *already* loaded as part of your project because they match, or are directly or indirectly imported by files that match, the `include` setting in `tsconfig.json`.  (See [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7849) for some background.)

I started with your configuration files and a blank source file but removed `@types/material-ui` because it's for the old `material-ui` package (which you don't have installed) and is just confusing matters.  At this point, if I invoke code completion with Ctrl-Space, I am *not* offered the Material UI components (`AppBar`, `Avatar`, ...).  But if I add an import, for example `import { AppBar } from "@material-ui/core";`, that forces the TypeScript server to load `@material-ui/core`, so now if I invoke code completion again, I am offered the rest of the Material UI components.  If you need auto import to work without an existing import, then you could add the appropriate `.d.ts` files to the `include` list in `tsconfig.json`, although then you'd want to use a separate `tsconfig.json` file for batch compilation so that you don't try to overwrite the JavaScript files in the `@material-ui/core` package.

I haven't tested any third-party auto-import plugins and can't speak about their behavior.