# VsCode clean Typescript project no auto import suggestions

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

When I create a new Node project using Typescript, VsCode auto import suggestions do not work at all.

**Steps to reproduce:**

Create a workspace directory.

Run `npm init` specifying `main.ts` as entrypoint file.

Import typescript cli `npm i typescript`

Create tsconfig.json `.\node_modules\.bin\tsc --init`

Create main.ts containing `console.log('Running');`

Transpile using `.\node_modules\.bin\tsc -w`

Run by clicking `Debug` in VsCode and using the default Nodejs launch config.

Import a library e.g. Rxjs Import typescript cli `npm i rxjs`

**Result:**

In main.ts attempting to  use any Rxjs type `Observable`, `BehaviourSubject`, global operators `from` `of` `sequenceEqual` etc results in no import assistance whatsoever.

I've read the VsCode Typescript docs, there is no hint there of what is wrong. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript

I've tried explicitly setting `include` and `exclude` directories in tsconfig.json which also has no effect.

Do I need to manually set some module resolution options in tsconfig or something.

I have no idea, I'm at a loss as to why this doesn't work.

UPDATE:

I managed to get VsCode auto import working by specifying

```
"typeRoots": [ "node_modules" ]
```

...in tsconfig.json

The results in a minor issue which is that tsc now reports the error

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '.bin'.
```

It appears the tsc now tries to read the contents of node_modules.bin which is not helpful. I've tried setting

```
"exclude": [ "./node_modules/.bin"]
```

in tsconfig, but that has no effect.

Comment: Possibly addressed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52471533).  I'm not confident enough to vote as a duplicate though.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving `main.js` as your entrypoint not `main.ts`

**Steps that I followed**:

Create a workspace directory.

Run npm init specifying `index.js` as entry point file.

Install typescript cli: `npm i typescript`

Create tsconfig.json: `.\node_modules\.bin\tsc --init`

Create index.ts containing `console.log('Running');`

Transpile using `.\node_modules\.bin\tsc -w`

Run by clicking Debug in VSCode and using the default Nodejs launch config.

Install a library e.g. Rxjs:  `npm i rxjs`

Now in index.ts file: `import { observable, BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs"`;

I was able to get those IntelliSense(import assistance)