# VSCode no intellisense for node_modules

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, intellisense

If i run

`npx create-react-app myapp --template typescript`

afterwards

`npm i rxjs`

Then start editing file `src/App.tsx`.

I can not for the life of me get the intellisense to work, *unless* i first `import {} from 'rxjs`.
The same goes for `@material-ui/core`.
I just freshly installed all of it. Vscode, npm, my whole computer basically.
I tried all sorts of NPM and NPM intellisense extentions but none work.

How do i enable the intellisense for node_modules without having to import the package first?

Comment: I don't think that will work without importing, if you are using typescript, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082763/vscode-intellisense-doesnt-suggest-angular-modules-until-imported-manually-in-t

Comment: It sure is possible. It's working on my work laptop without any problems, and without manually importing every type file from node modules. I just kind find the difference, apart from this is a PC and the Macbook is a macbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment has the gist of it..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52471533/1300796

Once you use a module in A file, it will be available in all files.
If you `import { of } from 'rxjs'` in file A, it will autoSuggest all `rxjs` module things in any other file.